# jQuery UI Plugin to append dialogs to form tag in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How would I make a jQuery plugin that does the following:

```
        var login = $("#login-dialog");

        login
            .dialog({ autoOpen: false })
            .parent(".ui-dialog")
            .appendTo("form");
```

but returns the same as .dialog would return (that is, `$("#login-dialog")` again)

so I could use

```
login.dialogForm({ autoOpen: false})
```

and still keep chaining for example...

```
login
    .dialogForm({ autoOpen: false}) 
    .find("input:submit, button, a")
    .button()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't that hard:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dialogForm = function (opts) {
        this.dialog(opts)
            .parent(".ui-dialog")
            .appendTo("form");

        return this;
    };
})($);
```